# FPDF Dashed Line Not Printing

Tags: php, printing, fpdf

I am trying to create a dashed line in fPDF using the [Dashes script](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script33.php).

When I generate the PDF, the dashed line renders properly, but when I try printing, it doesn't show up. I have tried on multiple printers with different settings.

Here is my code:

```
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Image(SCRIPT_ROOT."/images/pdf-cut.png",$x,$y,4,4);
$pdf->SetDash(4,2);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.2);
$pdf->Line(17,$y+2,200,$y+2);
$pdf->SetDash();
```

And what it looks like when rendered:

[Rendered Dashed Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k03pD.png)

When printing, the scissor shows up, but not the dashed line.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem at work. The dashed lines always showed up on the PDF viewer but on some printers (or from some printer drivers) the dashed lines would be missing. Add this function to your class to draw several line segments between two coordinates at any angle. Note: $dlen is length of the dash and $freq is the frequency that they are placed.

```
public function SegmentedLine($x,$y,$x2,$y2,$dlen = 1,$freq = 3){   
    if($x == $x2 and ($y2 - $y) < 0){   // vertical up
        $angle  = M_PI * 1.5;
    }elseif($x == $x2){                 // vertical down
        $angle  = M_PI * 0.5;
    }else{                              // not vertical
        $angle  = ($y2 - $y)/($x2 - $x);
        $angle  = atan($angle);
    }
    if($x > $x2){                       // NW or SW quadrant from start.
        $angle = M_PI + $angle;
    }
    $sin    = sin($angle);
    $cos    = cos($angle);
    $d      = sqrt(pow(($x2 - $x),2) + pow(($y2 - $y),2));
    for($i = 0; $i < ($d/$dlen); $i++){
        if($i % $freq == 0){                
            $sx = ($x + ($i * $dlen * $cos));
            $sy = ($y + ($i * $dlen * $sin));
            $ex = ($x + (($i + 1) * $dlen * $cos));
            $ey = ($y + (($i + 1) * $dlen * $sin));
            $this->Line($sx,$sy,$ex,$ey);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem at work. The dashed lines always showed up on the PDF viewer but on some printers (or from some printer drivers) the dashed lines would be missing. Add this function to your class to draw several line segments between two coordinates at any angle. Note: $dlen is

```
public function SegmentedLine($x,$y,$x2,$y2,$dlen = 1,$freq = 3){   
    if($x == $x2 and ($y2 - $y) < 0){   // vertical up
        $angle  = M_PI * 1.5;
    }elseif($x == $x2){                 // vertical down
        $angle  = M_PI * 0.5;
    }else{                              // not vertical
        $angle  = ($y2 - $y)/($x2 - $x);
        $angle  = atan($angle);
    }
    if($x > $x2){                       // NW or SW quadrant from start.
        $angle = M_PI + $angle;
    }
    $sin    = sin($angle);
    $cos    = cos($angle);
    $d      = sqrt(pow(($x2 - $x),2) + pow(($y2 - $y),2));
    for($i = 0; $i < ($d/$dlen); $i++){
        if($i % $freq == 0){                
            $sx = ($x + ($i * $dlen * $cos));
            $sy = ($y + ($i * $dlen * $sin));
            $ex = ($x + (($i + 1) * $dlen * $cos));
            $ey = ($y + (($i + 1) * $dlen * $sin));
            $this->Line($sx,$sy,$ex,$ey);
        }
    }
}
```